# using paramters in a fetch get call?

Tags: javascript, get, fetch

I am getting a 200 code from fetching the url but I cant figure out how to add the params. For now I just want to get the data to work with. how to get it to log the data?

```
  const params = {
  latitude: "33.775867",
  longitude: "-84.39733",
  elevation: "50",
  from_date: "2018-12-20",
  to_date: "2018-12-22",
  time: "08:00:00",
};

fetch("https://api.astronomyapi.com/api/v2/bodies/positions", params, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Basic " + btoa("apllication id:aplaciton secret"),
  },
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: fetch takes 2 arguments at most [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) - if you want to use params for a GET, you need to add them to the url

Comment: Checkout URLSearchParams class. You can use it to construct a query string which should be appended to the url. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams